# How can I optimize the following Python code, to prevent time exeption?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, optimization

Everybody. I wrote the following code. Please help me, to optimize this, when I submit in some test cases compiler writing  time-limit-exceeded 2.069s / 13.33Mb.

```
import math

N = int(input())
arr = [None]*N; new_list = []
stepen = 0; res = .0;

arr = input().split(" ")
arr = [float(h) for h in arr]

Q = int(input())
 
for j in range(Q):
    x, y = input().split()
    new_list.extend([int(x), int(y)])
        
for i, j in zip(new_list[0::2], new_list[1::2]):
    stepen = (j - i)+ 1
    res = math.prod(arr[i:j+1])
    print(pow(res, 1./stepen))
```

Comment: Would recommend a brief description of the problem you're solving rather than just the uncommented code.  It could be your algorithm is too slow for the problem.

Comment: Please add the task you're trying to solve. The only simple edit I can suggest here without given problem is to create new_list with comprehension instead of looping like
`new_list = [ u for _ in range(Q) for u in map(int, input().split()) ]`, but if Q is not very big, that shouldn't help. I suspect you've chosen not the right algorithm for the task. Maybe precaclulating of arr partial products (arr[0], arr[0]*arr[1],...,math.prod(arr)) can help, you'll be able then to calculate product of range with O(1) complexity with simple division. It may help if Q is greater than N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowest thing in your algorithm is the `math.prod(arr[i:j+1])`. If all the `x` and `y` inputs denote the entire range, you will surely TLE, as the calls to `prod` must loop over the entire range.

In order to avoid this, you must do a prefix product on your array. The idea is this: Keep a second array `pref`, with the property that `pref[i] = arr[i] * pref[i-1]`. As a result, `pref[i]` will be the product of everything at the `i`th position and before in `arr`.

Then to find the product between positions `i` and `j`, you want `pref[j] / pref[i-1]`. See if you can figure out why this gives the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you bro! You've helped me a lot